# Is it possible to reorder the content_panels in Wagtail admin?

Tags: python, django, wagtail, wagtail-admin

I am creating a Wagtail application where some models inherit fields from a base model. Unfortunately, these base fields are always displayed first in the form generated by Wagtail. For example:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    some_attribute = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    content_panels = [
        FieldPanel('some_attribute'),
    ]

@register_snippet
class ChildModel(BaseModel):
    title = models.TextField()

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('title'),
    ]
```

In Wagtail admin in the ChildModel editor, **some_attribute** would be displayed above **title** now, which is not very intuitive to users. Is there a way to change this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For snippets, the correct attribute name to use is `panels`, not `content_panels`. (For pages, the "content" in "content_panels" refers to the content tab rather than the "promote" tab - snippets don't have these tabs, unless you explicitly add them.) You probably also don't want to reference `Page.content_panels`, because this isn't a page model.

Since you don't have a `panels` attribute, it's falling back on listing the fields in definition order. Once you change `content_panels` to `panels`, you'll find that they get displayed in the order that you list them.

Comment: in order to get the BaseModel `panels` into the view, i then finally had to add `+ BaseModel.panels` to the `ChildModel.panels` array.